# How to add a custom block after product info in product view page magento2?

Tags: magento2, custom, product-view, custom-block

How to add a custom block in `product view` page after `product info`.
I have created a custom block via admin and its `id` is `category-block-1`
I have a custom them and i tried override `catalog_product_view.xml`.

**Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.block" template="Magento_Catalog::category-block.phtml" >
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Magento_Catalog/template/category-block.phtml**

```
<?php
  echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
          ->setBlockId('category-block-1')
          ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried My solution ?

Comment: @pawan yeah but it won't work

Comment: what issue you are getting ? Because I checked it and it working fine.

Comment: Good to know that, Welcome  :)

Comment: @Nismathvi did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you need `phtml`, You can directly call static block.
You can use below code in:

> [VENDOR_NAME]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="myPromo" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">category-block-1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope above will Help!

Comment: How does this work?
is this for all product page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` in layout file better way to call any template file is to call `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Another way is to call the static block directly in below file:

```
app/design/frontend/Your_vendor/your_theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the block named "content" has an "auto render" feature so you want to call
`<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.block'); ?>` inside 
`/[VENDOR_NAME]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

PS: You probably don't need to load the `class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"` again so better to use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`